# iOS GMSService undeclared identifier error

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps

I am getting:

> Use of undeclared Identifier GMSServices

error when using Google Maps IOS SDK. Below is the code in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    googleMapsApiKey =  @"AIzaSyB2x3fulSTaAE6F6sHgnLEHXpGt";
    [GMSServices provideAPIKey:googleMapsApiKey];
}
```

I have added the `GoogleMaps.framework` and `GoogleMaps.bundle` to the project Frameworks folder (Google Maps 1.9.2 with Xcode 6.4).

I am using a mixed Objective-C and Swift project. My bridging header file contains

```
#import <googleMaps><googleMaps.h>
```

Under Targets and Build Settings, the Objective-C Bridging Header is showing the correct path. 
I have refreshed my server and IOS keys to no avail.

Comment: From you code, you are working on an Objective-C appDelegate, so you should not need to create a bridge header file at all. Even thought u are working on a Swift project, your header filer should contains `#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>` instead. You can refer to [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start) for more details.

Comment: Just not sure how to mark this as answered?